DTMF detection by Twilio FROM Landlines/Phones
We have a android application that has a Twilio SDK integrated. we are using that to call a landlines/phones. I want a event to be generated when the person punches/keys a digit (say 9) from the landline.
We tried different things. we understand that DTMF doesn't get read when punched from a landline/phone...

Help me understand the scenario so I can help you in the best way.
Are you playing audio to induce the user to type something?
If so, are you using response.gather with the parameters to collect the dtmf?
e.g.: < Gather input="speech dtmf" timeout="3" numDigits="1"><say/play ...
If you do not specify the tag parameters, Twilio will not collect the dtmf
